# Cannot convert from string to System.IO.Stream

Tags: xamarin.forms

Here's my code for StreamReader in Xamarin Forms What I want is simply read a file and convert it into byte array but when I try this code I simply get this error that is Cannot convert from string to System.IO.Stream

```
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            buffer = new byte[(int)sr.BaseStream.Length];
            await sr.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, (int)sr.BaseStream.Length);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

`StreamReader` operates upon an existing `Stream`. But you still need to open or create that underlying stream first by using the device operating system. The process of doing this is slightly different on each platform, and so you can't put that part of your code into the PCL project.

See the section of the documentation titled *"Saving and Loading Files"* here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using xamarin dependency service and use FileStream to read the bytes

```
public byte[] ImageToBinary(string imagePath)
    {

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Close();
        return buffer;
    }
```